# How do I add a filename to images attached to emails using javax.mail.jar

Tags: java, email

I'm able to successfully send myself an email with an image, however, the image comes as a file named noname (on gmail, anyway). How can I change the file name of the image I am attaching to the email?

Here is the section of code I am using for sending an email with an image:

```
    public void SendEmail(
            String smtp_host_, 
            String smtp_port_, 
            String smtp_username_, 
            String smtp_password_,
            String to_,
            String subject_,
            String body_,
            String image_path_) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtp_host_);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtp_port_);

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(smtp_username_, smtp_password_);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

            message.setSubject(subject_);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(smtp_username_));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to_));

            MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setContent(body_, "text/html");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(image_path_);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            message.setContent(multipart);

            Transport transport = session.getTransport();
            transport.connect();
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
            transport.close();
        }
        catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A shorthand for the FileDataSource and setDataHandler calls is the [attachFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile-java.io.File-) method, which should set the name in the body part as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setFileName(String)`.

You can do it after creating the part:

```
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
((MimeBodyPart) messageBodyPart).setFileName("filename.ext");
```

See java docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#setFileName-java.lang.String-)